# How do I store a CSS class in browser preferences?

Tags: javascript, css, local-storage

So, this is the piece of code I have. It's applied on a Blogger site. It has a button that styles the page in a dark mode. This is all working fine.

(HTML, CSS, Script, in that order)

```
<center>
<a href="FBLINK" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
<a href="TWITTERLINK" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
<button class="button" onclick="myFunction()">&#9680;</button>
</center>

<style>
.dark-mode {
  background-color: #262626;
  color: #d9d9d9;
}
.dark-mode a, .dark-mode span, .dark-mode h2 a, .dark-mode h1, .dark-mode h2, .dark-mode h3, .dark-mode h4, .dark-mode h5, .dark-mode h6, .dark-mode .post-box-title, .dark-mode strong.tag-heading {
  color: #d9d9d9;
}

.dark-mode div#sidebar h2 span {
  background-color: #262626;
  border-color: #e5e5e5;
}

.dark-mode #sidebar .widget {
  border-color: #e5e5e5;
}
.dark-mode .post-entry, .dark-mode .entry-meta {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(229,229,229,0.2);
}
.dark-mode div#blog-pager {
  color: #d9d9d9;
  background-color: #323232;
}
</style>

<script>
function myFunction() {
   var element = document.body;
   element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
}
</script>
```

The thing is, I wanna storage these dark mode settings on the user browser.

Already tried `sessionStorage` and `localStorage`, but not sure if I'm using the code in the right place, and using the right key/value combo (which I have: key is "style" or "class" and value is "dark-mode").

Is it between these `<script>` tags? Is it between a proper JavaScript tag? Is it in *that* piece of code? For now, let's use `localStorage` as the main setting.

Hope I was clear enough, and thanks for the help!

Comment: i think that its better to extract it into a css file and store the theme in localstorage like this : localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark-theme.css');

Comment: I'll save that and see if it works. Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can name the localstorage key all you want, but remember to act on the value accordingly.

```
<button onclick="toggleMode()">Toggle theme</button>

<script>
// Theme mode key name
const LS_THEME_KEY = "theme_mode";
// Possible theme mode local storage values
const THEME_MODE_LIGHT = 0;
const THEME_MODE_DARK = 1;
// Class to be applied when dark mode is active
const BODY_DARK_MODE_CLASS = "dark-mode";
// Default theme
const DEFAULT_THEME_MODE = THEME_MODE_DARK;

// Look up current theme mode and modify the body
// tag class list accordingly.
const syncBodyClassList = (setValue) => {
  const currThemeMode = setValue !== undefined ? setValue : parseInt(localStorage.getItem(LS_THEME_KEY) || DEFAULT_THEME_MODE);
  if (currThemeMode === THEME_MODE_DARK) {
    // turn the dark theme on
    document.body.classList.add(BODY_DARK_MODE_CLASS);
  } else {
    // turn the dark theme off
    document.body.classList.remove(BODY_DARK_MODE_CLASS);
  }
};

const setThemeMode = (mode) => {
  localStorage.setItem(LS_THEME_KEY, mode);
  syncBodyClassList(mode);
}

// Toggle current theme and save it into the local storage
function toggleMode() {
  const currentValue = parseInt(localStorage.getItem(LS_THEME_KEY) || DEFAULT_THEME_MODE);
  if (currentValue === THEME_MODE_DARK) {
    setThemeMode(THEME_MODE_LIGHT);
  } else {
    setThemeMode(THEME_MODE_DARK);
  }
}

const initPage = () => {
  syncBodyClassList();
}

initPage();
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I had a hard time trying to find the right code - also, because I'm kinda a newbie on how scripts works. Grateful again for the fast response! :)